# Django: parametric class-based views

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am trying to use generic CreateView class to handle forms for a set of models inherited from the same base class.

```
class BaseContent(models.Model):
    ...

class XContent(BaseContent):
    ...

class YContent(BaseContent):
    ...
```

To keep things DRY, I want to define one CreateView class that will handle all inherited classes from BaseContent.

The url pattern for that view is:

```
url(r'^content/add/(?P<model_name>\w+)/$', ContentCreateView.as_view(), name='content_add')
```

Something like this should work:

```
class ContentCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'content_form.html'

    def get_model(self, request):
        # 'content' is the name of the application; model_name is 'xcontent', 'ycontent', ...
        return ContentType.objects.get_by_natural_key('content', self.model_name)
```

But I am getting this exception:

```
ContentCreateView is missing a queryset. Define ContentCreateView.model, ContentCreateView.queryset, or override ContentCreateView.get_object().
```

This suggestion does not seem to hold as I am not willing to set a class attribute like `model` or `queryset` to keep the model form generated dynamic. Overriding the `get_object` does not seem relevant for creating an object.

I tried overriding `get_queryset()` but this method does not accept the `request` parameter, nor have access to `self.model_name` which comes from the url pattern.

Long story short, how can I make a CreateView use a dynamic form based on a parameter passed from the url?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that request and model_name would be set as instance variables, so you could self.request and self.model_name inside get_queryset() method. Didn't try that thought.

Comment: yes, View class which is an ancestor of CreateView sets the kwargs from the url as instance variables. but `self.model_name` is not accessible to `get_queryset()` as it comes from another mixin while `self.request` is. if i pass the model name as a `get` parameter i will be able to do what i want but it won't be nice. imo, the way the inheritance and mixins are organized in class based views and lack of documentation makes it very complicated to trace class methods and attributes.

Comment: Can't you just create form classes for each of the models and over ride get_form_class method of `ModelFormMixin` to get the relevant form for the view based on the request params?

Comment: as a last resort, yes. but it is not the generic dry way i am after because i have to define a form class for each of the inherited models. just like `get_form_class`, why doesn't `get_model` way work without setting a queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `model` attribute from your your `urls.py`, depending on the url being called:

```
url(r'^content/add/x/$', 
    ContentCreateView.as_view(model=XContent), name='x_content_add'),
url(r'^content/add/y/$', 
    ContentCreateView.as_view(model=YContent), name='y_content_add')
```

I admit it's not perfect as you are repeating yourself a bit, but therefore you have the advantage of having different names for the same view, depending on the model! Besides that you could also do something similar with overriding `form_class`...

Comment: as_view() does not seem to accept arguments. the way you suggested raises: `as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`. i modified the url pattern this way: `url(r'^add/x/$', ContentCreateView.as_view(), {'queryset':XContent.objects.all()})` but the kwarg does not seem to be passed to the class instance: `ContentCreateView is missing a queryset`.

Comment: Sorry my fault, of course you have to pass it as kwargs, not as dict, edited the answer!

Comment: thanks for the update, it is alright now. i hope it will be documented soon, though it is not easy with multiple levels of multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem for some time, but found the solution. You need to override the dispatch method, defined in as_view() (django.views.generic.base), something like this:

```
class ContentCreateView(CreateView):    
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        for app in ['foo', 'bar']:
            model = models.get_model(app, kwargs['modelname'])
            if model:
                self.model = model
                break

        return super(GenericEdit, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    ...
    ...
```